# How to monitor failed AWS EMR Steps using Datadog

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-emr, datadog

I was reading the [Datadog docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/amazon_emr/) on how to monitor AWS Elastic Map Reduce using Datadog because I need to get metrics for failed EMR steps.
[LIKE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYQy2.png)

I think the most accurate metric is [aws.elasticmapreduce.jobs_failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckxgp.png) but as the image says, is only available for Hadoop V1, but I'm using Hadoop V2... so I don't see it in my [Datadog Metric Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Q7c.png)

- Can someone help me?
- Is there a replacement for that metric in Hadoop v2?
- Is there another way to monitor failed EMR steps with Datadog?
- The steps are Sqoop jobs